# Unable to get a command executed in python

Tags: python

I am unable to run the following command
C:\Users\deepa>python ..\scrape.py
It gives me an error
python: can't open file 'C:\Users\scrape.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

I have already set environment variables to get python executed from any directory.

Comment: Well, it is complaining that there is no file `C:\Users\scrape.py`. This has nothing to do with environment variables. Make sure there is a file at that location

Comment: Read the error message. Is scrape.py so located ? No. Then the error lies in how you point to it. Hint: the `..\ ` ..

Comment: Looks like the file is in Deepa directory. You can use `python scrape.py` or if it is outside Deepa directory just do ,`python .\scrape.py`

Answer (score 0):

If you have set your environment variables then you don't need to pass the path of the file (which you are passing is incorrect) while running the code. Just you can mention file name and it will get executed.

```
python scrape.py
```

Comment: I get the same error when i do python scrape.py. Any ideas?

Comment: @Deepanshu At what location your file is located?

Answer (score 0):

For your command:

```
C:\Users\deepa>python ..\scrape.py
```

The problem is not related to the python path, it's about the **..\scrape.py**,
Please make sure this python script (scrape.py) is in the right place, I recommend you use **absolute path** instead of **related path**, for example:

```
C:\Users\deepa>python D:\test\test.py
```

**D:\test\test.py** is the absolute path of this python script (scrape.py), or you can drag this file into your terminal/cmd/PowerShell etc., you will see its **absolute path**.